# Store file path into a QString [Qt]

Tags: qt, path, filenames

I want to open a file via a Dialog File and then store the file path into a text file. 
The problem is that when I use the absoluteFilePath() function I get an error. Here is my code:

```
filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open File","*.H86;;*.glo");

//enregistrer le dernier chemin utilisé pour ouvrir un fichier
FILE* fichier = NULL;
fichier = fopen("LastPath.txt","w");
if(fichier != NULL)
{

    QString filename_fichier_choisi = filename.QFileInfo::absoluteFilePath();
    fputs(filename_fichier_choisi.toLatin1(),fichier);

    //fichier->write(filename.toLatin1());
}
fclose(fichier);
```

The error I get is "QFileInfo is not a base of QString.
Which function could I use to get the path as a String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why are you mixing Qt and FILE* and not using QFile directly?

You can do  the following to get the file path:

```
QString file = QFileInfo(filename).absoluteFilePath();
```

or if you only want the folder:

```
QString folder = QFileInfo(filename).absolutePath();
```

It seems that you are new to C++. You first need an object of a specific type before you can call functions on that type. Thus `QFileInfo(filename)` creates an `QFileInfo` object and then the `.absoluteFilePath()` calls the function on the created object.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I corrected my code so not to use FILE* but QFile and i still have a problem: the folder QString still contains the name of my file when I only want the path.

Comment: @AlexandreNader, Sorry I have updated the answer to give you the folder.

Comment: Thank you again for your help